# sonarqube eclipse plugin false positives

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I'm currently using sonar version 3.7, with Eclipse plugin 3.3 and Eclipse Kepler.

All seems to working fine, apart from if I set a false positive on the server, this seems to be ignored on the Eclipse plugin (i.e. the issue that I'd previously set up on the server as a false positive is still appearing in Eclipse)

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Did you run another analysis in Eclipse after flagging the issue false positive on the server?

Answer (score -1):

The documentation states that running an analysis from Eclipse is [incremental by default](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+SonarQube+in+Eclipse#WorkingwithSonarQubeinEclipse-RunninganAnalysis) and only checks modified or new files. If you have not touched the file with the false-positive, it might therefore not update its issues.